# Show array on vue view section without braces

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I need to show below array on view section but I got exact array with braces I need it without braces and quotations

Array
["WHATSAPP", "2G", "CLIQ"]

Code

```
<v-col cols="12" md="4" class="d-flex">
  <v-chip color="#fff" label>
    <v-icon left> mdi-information-outline </v-icon>Activation
    Not Allowed
  </v-chip>
  <v-chip label>
    {{ definitionObj.actnotallow }}
  </v-chip>
</v-col>
```

Way it prints

[image]

Way I need to print it

WHATSAPP, 2G, CLIQ

Comment: `{{ definitionObj.actnotallow.join(", ") }}`

Comment: @Phil Some arrays doesn't have value and I got Cannot read property 'join' of undefined error and not display anything on page how to overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the perfect opportunity to use a computed property

```html
<v-chip label>
  {{ formattedActNotAllow }}
</v-chip>
```

```js
computed: {
  formattedActNotAllow: ({ definitionObj }) =>
    definitionObj.actnotallow?.join(", ")
}
```